# php - check for paypal recurring payment status

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

I have made a simple script using PayPal PHP SDK, I have created a recurring payment, however, I am not sure how I can check for each user payment status each month?

Because I need to check if the payment was successful or no monthly, so I can update the user DB values etc.

Used: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/

Any specific API call for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable IPN from the PayPal business account to get auto-notification about recurring payments.

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, including automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.

To know more about it, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

**Step 1**:
Enable IPN from your PayPal business account, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#id089EG030E5Z)

**Step 2**: [Implement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) the IPN listener on your server to receive the recurring payment notification.